# "The domain name '' you have specified is invalid" error while uploading aab to play console

Tags: android, google-play, android-app-bundle

While uploading my aab to play store I get this error:

> The domain name '' you have specified is invalid. Specify a valid domain name.

It's signed and I get this error when building both from Android studio and console. I cant understand what "domain name" did I specify incorrectly (or left empty). What could be the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The domain name is used for your unique app's package name. It recommended reversing your domain name to create your package name i.e. *com.yourDomainName.yourAppName* to avoid conflicts with other apps.
You can find your package name in your **Project Settings under App (Bundle) ID**.
Your package name should be **all lower case**.
None of the segments should begin with a number.
None of the segments should have an accent on the characters.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Now we have a multi module project, with one general gradle file. In this gradle file we didnt specify applicationId, it was specified as "package" in our main module's mainfest. Probably I have to split gradle files, make one for each module and add applicationId to the base one. Will dig in this direction, thanks!